# Elasticsearch work at localhost but not when dockerized

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to ES so i decided to post mostly codes. When running at local, although elasticsearch health is yellow(I dont know what it means exactly) , its working well but in docker-compose my nodejs service cannot connect to elasticsearch that is running withouth any problem in docker , too. I really do not know anything about this error. I will be glad if you help, thanks.

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis_container
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes/cache:/data
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb_container
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes/mongo_data:/data/db
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_container
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=ensar
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=fw
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ensar
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ensar
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ensar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ensar
      - POSTGRES_DB=fw
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq_container
    image: rabbitmq:3.13.0-rc.4-management-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=ensar
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=ensar
    ports:
      # amqp protocol ports
      - '5672:5672'
      # management ui
      - '15672:15672'
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch_container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx1g -Xms1g
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      discovery.type: single-node
      xpack.security.enabled: "false"
      xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled: "true"
      xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: "true"
      xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: "true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes/elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  kibana:
    container_name: kibana_container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.12.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://elasticsearch_container:9200"]
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    networks:
      - elastic
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml/:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  service_notification:
    container_name: service_notification_container
    build:
      context: ../services/service_notification
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
    env_file: ../services/service_notification/.env
    environment:
      - ENABLE_APM=1
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - RABBITMQ_ENDPOINT=amqp://ensar:ensar@rabbitmq_container:5672
      - SENDER_EMAIL=brycen.feil@ethereal.email
      - SENDER_EMAIL_PASSWORD=rxQAwnMbQqU3mQ6ck5
      - ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch_container:9200
      - ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8200
      - ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN=
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
networks:
  elastic:
    name: elastic
    driver: bridge
```

This is config

```
const elasticSearchClient = new Client({
  node: `${config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}`,
  Connection: HttpConnection,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  sniffOnStart: true
});

export async function checkConnection(): Promise<void> {
  let isConnected = false;
  while (!isConnected) {
    try {
      const health: ClusterHealthResponse = await elasticSearchClient.cluster.health({});
      log.info(`NotificationService Elasticsearch health status - ${health.status}`);
      isConnected = true;
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('Connection to Elasticsearch failed. Retrying...');
      log.log('error', 'NotificationService checkConnection() method:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

This is .env

> ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200

This is error

```
2024-02-21 17:55:12 ERROR:
2024-02-21 17:55:12     message: "Connection to Elasticsearch failed. Retrying..."
2024-02-21 17:55:12     service: "notificationElasticSearchServer"
2024-02-21 17:55:12 ERROR (ConnectionError):
2024-02-21 17:55:12     message: "NotificationService checkConnection() method: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:9200"
2024-02-21 17:55:12     meta: {
2024-02-21 17:55:12       "headers": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12       "meta": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "aborted": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "attempts": 3,
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "connection": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "_openRequests": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "agent": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "_events": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "_eventsCount": 2,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "defaultPort": 80,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "freeSockets": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "keepAlive": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "keepAliveMsecs": 1000,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "maxFreeSockets": 256,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "maxSockets": 256,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "maxTotalSockets": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "options": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "keepAlive": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "keepAliveMsecs": 1000,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "maxFreeSockets": 256,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "maxSockets": 256,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "noDelay": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "path": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "scheduling": "lifo"
2024-02-21 17:55:12             },
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "protocol": "http:",
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "requests": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "scheduling": "lifo",
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "sockets": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "elasticsearch_container:9200:": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                 "0": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_closeAfterHandlingError": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_events": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "close": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "connect": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "timeout": {}
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   },
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_eventsCount": 8,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_hadError": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_host": "elasticsearch_container",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_httpMessage": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_closed": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_contentLength": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_defaultKeepAlive": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_ended": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_events": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_eventsCount": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_hasBody": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_header": "GET /_cluster/health HTTP/1.1\r\nuser-agent: elasticsearch-js/8.12.1 (linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x64; Node.js 21.6.2; Transport 8.4.0)\r\nx-elastic-client-meta: es=8.12.1,js=21.6.2,t=8.4.0,hc=21.6.2\r\naccept: application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8,text/plain\r\nHost: elasticsearch_container:9200\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_headerSent": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_keepAliveTimeout": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_last": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_removedConnection": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_removedContLen": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_removedTE": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "_trailer": "",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "aborted": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "agent": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "chunkedEncoding": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "destroyed": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "finished": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "host": "elasticsearch_container",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "maxHeadersCount": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "maxRequestsOnConnectionReached": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "method": "GET",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "outputData": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "outputSize": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "parser": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "path": "/_cluster/health",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "protocol": "http:",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "res": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "reusedSocket": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "sendDate": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "shouldKeepAlive": true,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "strictContentLength": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "timeout": 60000,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "upgradeOrConnect": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "useChunkedEncodingByDefault": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "writable": true
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   },
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_parent": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_pendingData": "GET /_cluster/health HTTP/1.1\r\nuser-agent: elasticsearch-js/8.12.1 (linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x64; Node.js 21.6.2; Transport 8.4.0)\r\nx-elastic-client-meta: es=8.12.1,js=21.6.2,t=8.4.0,hc=21.6.2\r\naccept: application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8,text/plain\r\nHost: elasticsearch_container:9200\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_pendingEncoding": "latin1",
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_readableState": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "awaitDrainWriters": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "buffer": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "bufferIndex": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "highWaterMark": 16384,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "length": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "pipes": {}
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   },
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_server": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_sockname": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "_writableState": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "bufferedIndex": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "corked": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "highWaterMark": 16384,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "length": 346,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "pendingcb": 1,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                     "writelen": 346
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   },
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "allowHalfOpen": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "connecting": false,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "parser": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "server": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12                   "timeout": 60000
2024-02-21 17:55:12                 }
2024-02-21 17:55:12               }
2024-02-21 17:55:12             },
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "totalSocketCount": 1
2024-02-21 17:55:12           },
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "deadCount": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "headers": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "id": "http://elasticsearch_container:9200/",
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "resurrectTimeout": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "timeout": 30000,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "tls": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "url": "http://elasticsearch_container:9200/",
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "weight": 1000
2024-02-21 17:55:12         },
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "context": null,
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "name": "elasticsearch-js",
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "request": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "id": 397,
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "options": {},
2024-02-21 17:55:12           "params": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "headers": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "accept": "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8,text/plain",
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "user-agent": "elasticsearch-js/8.12.1 (linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x64; Node.js 21.6.2; Transport 8.4.0)",
2024-02-21 17:55:12               "x-elastic-client-meta": "es=8.12.1,js=21.6.2,t=8.4.0,hc=21.6.2"
2024-02-21 17:55:12             },
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "method": "GET",
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "path": "/_cluster/health",
2024-02-21 17:55:12             "querystring": ""
2024-02-21 17:55:12           }
2024-02-21 17:55:12         }
2024-02-21 17:55:12       },
2024-02-21 17:55:12       "statusCode": 0,
2024-02-21 17:55:12       "warnings": null
2024-02-21 17:55:12     }
2024-02-21 17:55:12     options: {
2024-02-21 17:55:12       "redaction": {
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "additionalKeys": [],
2024-02-21 17:55:12         "type": "replace"
2024-02-21 17:55:12       }
2024-02-21 17:55:12     }
2024-02-21 17:55:12     service: "notificationElasticSearchServer"
2024-02-21 17:55:12     stack: "ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:9200\n    at SniffingTransport.request (/app/node_modules/@elastic/transport/src/Transport.ts:603:17)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async Cluster.health (/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/src/api/api/cluster.ts:256:12)"
```

Comment: Are you running the nodejs service also in a container? Is it visible in your docker-compose (service_notification perhaps)? Also, your error log says the url http://elasticsearch_container:9200/ (which seems correct) but earlier you say it's http://localhost:9200. Which one is actually in use now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer , When docker compose up elasticsearch runs at localhost:9200 and http://elasticsearch_container:9200 cannot be reached. Yes nodejs service is also in running in a container and its visible.